# How to use "and" in this case

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I would like to use **and** with my following sentence but I feel my structure is wrong.

**We used lower and upper tails dependency shapes and positive and negative dependency shapes.**

How can I use **and** with this sentence? any idea or help, please?

Comment: By far the neatest solution is to use **as well as** - although that doesn't answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really wish to remain using **and**, then to improve the clarity of how the two items are grouped, I would suggest the use of ampersands in place of *and* in between *lower* and *upper*, e.g.:

> We used lower **&** upper tails dependency shapes and positive **&** negative dependency shapes.

However, there are several ways in which you could avoid the **and** repetition entirely:

> We used lower & upper tails dependency shapes **in addition to** positive & negative dependency shapes.

> We used lower & upper tails dependency shapes **as well as** positive & negative dependency shapes. *<sub>(credit: @RonaldSole)</sub>*

> We used lower & upper tails dependency shapes **coupled with** positive & negative dependency shapes.

(Though, that last option may depend somewhat on the context)

Answer (score 0):

Your structure doesn't seem to be incorrect, though there may be better ways to express its meaning.

You can also write it as:

> We used shapes with both lower/upper tails dependency and positive/negative dependency.